# Can MathJax be enabled on Materials.SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Can a CM help enable MathJax on this site, as it is expected that there will be considerable mathematics involved in posts?

Comment: I'm going to propose making this the hub post for this feature. We all had the same idea at once and there are about 4 posts about this now. I would also recommend including mhchem, a mathjax for writing chemical formulas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adam has switched this site setting on for y'all, so have fun!

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Thank you so much @Catija!

Comment: Could you also enable the mhchem extension, I'd guess we'll heave to write a few formulas here, too.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Should be good.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!